# A little question about notation: set operators or logic operators

Tags: notation

The question arise from the definition of conditional probability, that is defined as

$$\Pr[A\cap B]=\Pr[A|B]\cdot\Pr[B]$$

Alternatively, in the context of cummulative joint probability distributions we can write

$$F_{XY}(x,y)=\Pr[X\le x, Y\le y]\overset{?}{=}\begin{cases}\Pr[X\le x \cap Y\le y] & \text{it is this expression correct?} \\ \Pr[X\le x \land Y\le y] & \text{it is this expression correct?} \end{cases}$$

I generally tend when writing faster to write the operator $\land$ because to my mind comes "this must happen AND this must happen too". I dont have clear reason to think that is incorrect but I suppose it must be because no one use it.

Can someone clarify the difference on the use of set operators or logic operators (in a short way)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You meant $ Pr[X \leq x \cap Y\leq y]$ and $ Pr[X \leq x \wedge Y\leq y]$ I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $\operatorname{Pr}[X \leq x]$ is an abuse of notation - nothing wrong with that, a good abuse of notation makes things much more concise and easy to read. It is a shorthand for $\operatorname{Pr}[\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}]$, if $X$ is a random variable with domain $\Omega$.

And then $\operatorname{Pr}[X \leq x \land Y \leq y]$ would be the shorthand for $\operatorname{Pr}[\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x \land Y(\omega) \leq y\}]$, while $\operatorname{Pr}[X \leq x \cap Y \leq y]$ would be shorthand for $\operatorname{Pr}[\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} \cap \{ \omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega) \leq y\}]$. Which is of course the same set. So both forms are usable, just slightly different abuses of notation.

Answer (score 1):

To be rigorous, the application $Pr$ is evaluated on **sets**, rather than logic propositions, so the first would be more correct. Besides, I've never seen the use of $\wedge $ in these cases. the use of "$,$" is frequent instead.

On the other hand this wouldn't be that bad...